# Understanding of “owning side” and “inverse side” concepts in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Please, could anybody explain with examples idea of “owning side” and “inverse side” concepts in Doctrine?  I understand that they are necessary to organize bidirectional relationship, but I can’t realize following text from Doctrine documentation ([link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)):

> There are 2 references on each side of the association and these 2
>   references both represent the same association but can change
>   independently of one another.

1. Why there are 2 references on each side, and in total 4? Now, in
   total,  I see only 2 references From A (owning side) to B (inverse
   side), and from B to A.
2. In which situations references can be changed independently of one
   another?
3. What happens in memory that trigger necessity of “owning side ” and
   “ inverse side usage?
4. What is difference between “reference” and “association”?

**Edit** 
For example, I have entities Customer (owning side) and Company (inverse side). At first, I do following:

```
$customer = new  Customer(); 
$company = new Company();
$customer->setCompany($company);
$company->setCustomer($customer);
```

Then I can have two scenarios:

Scenario 1

```
$company->getCustomer()->setName(‘John’);
$entityManager->persist($company);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Scenario 2

```
$customer->getCompany()->setLicenseNumber(‘24535’);
$entityManager->persist($company);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Do I understand rightly, that in first case association will be persisted correctly, because owning side (through getCustomer()) is changed, but in second case it will be ignored, because  owning side is not changed?

Comment: I think your second scenario doesn't really make sense. You get company, change a company property and persist the company. This will always work of course... In scenario one you update user and persist company. You said that company is the inverse side, so the change to customer is not persisted. You should explicitly call `persist` on `$customer` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should read as: *There are 2 references, **one** on each side of the association*
    So there are not 4 but 2...
2. *in a correct application the semantics of the bidirectional association are properly maintained by the application developer* 
   In other words they can, but should not if you correctly implement the relationship.
3. *Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored.*
   So in principle (for keeping your database model up to date) only maintaining the owning side would suffice, but in your object model you would (maybe) like to access your associations from the inverse side as well and when you access the inverse side you want the values (for example an array collection on inverse side) to be correct, that is why you should take care of both sides.
4. I think something like this: the association is the actual relationship, references are like the handles to this relationship.

I tried to add *quotes* from the documentation to my answer. Please leave a comment if you/someone does not agree with my answer or if you see a possibility to improve the explanations...

### UPDATE:

Example for your `Company` and `User`...

`Customer` entity:

```
class Customer
{
    // ...

    /** ONE-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, OWNING SIDE
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="customer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $company;

    // ...

    /**
     * Set company method
     *
     * @param Company $company
     */
    public function setCompany( Company $company )
    {
       $this->company = $company; 
       $company->setCustomer( $this );
    }
}
```

`Company` entity:

```
class Company
{
    // ...

    /** ONE-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, INVERSE SIDE
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="company")
     */
    private $customer;

    // ...
}
```

An example:

```
$company= $em->find('Application\Entity\Company', 1);
$customer = $em->find('Application\Entity\Customer', 1);

$customer->setCompany($company);
$em->persist($customer);
$em->flush();
```

If you now do `$customer = $company->getCustomer();` you will get a `Customer` with id 1.

And now imagine not having the line `$company->setCustomer( $this );` in the `setCompany` method. If you then do `$customer = $company->getCustomer();` after setting `$company` you will not get a `Customer` with id 1. In other words the association on inverse side does not correspond with your database model and does not correspond with the reference on the owning side.

Comment: Thank you for answer!  2. It would be nice to have simple example, when that 2 references are changed independently of one another. For 3. point, please check my question update.

Comment: @Molarro I added an example.