# Doctrine: owning side and inverse side

Tags: php, doctrine, associations, object-model

Hellow, in de Doctrine documentations says:
'Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.'

I have read other posts here, but I can't find an example that makes me understand why if there is a change in the inverse side this would not be persisted by doctrine.

I take the example of the post: [Understanding of “owning side” and “inverse side” concepts in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652605/understanding-of-owning-side-and-inverse-side-concepts-in-doctrine)

`Customer` entity:

```
class Customer
{
    // ...

    /** ONE-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, OWNING SIDE
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="customer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $company;

    // ...

    /**
     * Set company method
     *
     * @param Company $company
     */
    public function setCompany( Company $company )
    {
       $this->company = $company; 
       $company->setCustomer( $this );
    }
}
```

`Company` entity:

```
class Company
{
    // ...

    /** ONE-TO-ONE BIDIRECTIONAL, INVERSE SIDE
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="company")
     */
    private $customer;

    // ...
}
```

and I have two questions:
1. How would be setCustomer method in Company Entity? (to reflect this database model)
2. In that case it could be that a change in the Company Entity could not be persisted by doctrine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between inversedBy and mappedBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493865/what-is-the-difference-between-inversedby-and-mappedby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out all the things that have in your head about `Owning side` and `Inversed side`. **These are nothing but some concepts that help Doctrine hydrate data into related models**.

Read the following quotation from the Doctrine doc. This may somewhat help understand the concept of `Owning side` and `Inversed side`.

> "Owning side" and "inverse side" are technical concepts of the ORM
>   technology, not concepts of your domain model. What you consider as
>   the owning side in your domain model can be different from what the
>   owning side is for Doctrine. These are unrelated.

Another quotation from the Doctrine doc:

> Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for
>   changes.

This means **the owning side of an association is the entity with the table containing the foreign key**. Therefore, the table containing foreign key will only be considered by doctrine for changes.

Once again from the Doctrine doc:

- OneToOne - **One instance of the current Entity refers to One instance of the referred Entity**.
- The owning side of a **OneToOne** assocation is the entity with the table containing the foreign key

Here one instance of **Company** refers to one instance of the referred entity **Customer** or vice versa.

When we talk about **OneToOne** association like your example above, the **owning side** would be the entity with the table containing the foreign key, therefore, **Customer** entity.

With your example, Doctrine will create tables like the below:

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    company_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES Company(id);
```

Now if you want to get data for a customer associated with a company then the query would be:

```
SELECT Company.id AS CompanyID, Customer.id AS CustomerID
FROM Company
LEFT JOIN Customer ON Company.id = Customer.company.id;
```

The returned result from this type of query will be hydrated into both models by Doctrine.

Comment: thank, I still have doubts, I need an example of a case in which Doctrine would ignore a persist.
for example:
$company = new Company();
$entityManager->persist($company);
$entityManager->flush();

This would not be saved in database?

Comment: Yes this would also be saved in database. Did you notice the `setCompany()` method in the `Customer` entity? This is made by doctrine by using/checking the owning side of the association.